# Is there some framework to realize this kind of "feature request voting"?

Tags: asp.net

If you have a look at VS feauture request and NDepend feature request you'll find out that they are exactly the same.

How is it possible? Are they using the same tool? Do you know if it is opensource and/or free?

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/filters/top

Comment: They're the same because they're both UserVoice sites. It's not free or open source, but you can pay for your own site as it's offered as  Software as a Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked you provided is to a UserVoice.com site, which is apparently in use by the Visual Studio product team.

I see that NDepend is [also using UserVoice.com](http://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice).

Since they're both using UserVoice, you would expect them to look similar.  You can learn more about UserVoice [here](https://www.uservoice.com/).  UserVoice is a commercial product.